# How to create/edit .class file codes

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, smb

I would like to know if there is a way to edit the codes in a class file? Because I dont seem to be able to compile a java file into a class file with the use of cmd as it will always detect errors . The Jar file that I am using already have its own existing class files and I would like to update one of the the .class file with a few lines of codes. But when I copied the codes from the class file and put it into a java file together with my added lines of codes, and then try compiling it using cmd, the cmd will generate error whenever I tried to compile it to generate the class file.

Does that mean that I will need to de-compile the whole jar file and make it into a java file and then recompile it into a class file then make it into a new jar file again,? In order to achieve what I am trying to do?

Right now I am using this JCIFS jar file and I would like to add in some lines of codes into one of the class file. I am refering to this "https://code.google.com/p/android-smb-streaming/" as a guide and I discovered that this person is able to customize / add a new class file with the same lines of codes from the existing class in the jar file together with his own added lines of codes.

May I know how do I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: creating .class in the sense compiler will take care of it and we cannot modify or edit .class files

Comment: then may I know if there are any possible ways to do it because according to what I had discovered and also had posted the link above . I found out that the person had created his own .class that have the same codes from the existing .class file , just that this new .class file that he created have a some new lines of codes added into this class that he had created. And so I am thinking that it is possible to create one to be included into the jar file, however whenever I tried compiling the java file into a class file , it keeps giving me errors T.T

Comment: You'd do better to learn to understand and fix your errors.

Comment: That means, the only way to do it is to have the whole java file and then make it into a jar file ?

Comment: There are tools like CGLIB or javassist that allows to dynamically patch java classes after they have been loaded in memory. And you can find the sources of the compiler. So yes the `.class` files **are** files and you could patch them, and so are `.jar` ones. But you surely **do not want** to do that : if compiler detects errors, the code you want to add is likely to break !

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do here is a common situation: you found a bug/feature request for an open source project.

Instead of hacking it you could try to contact the author of the library, submit your contribution and wait until it gets a new release so it has your new cool feature.

On the other hand, you can use the exposed API to customize it for your needs, e.g., create a specific subclass that overrides the required method containing that few lines of code and use the API in a way that it uses your implementation.

If you want to go the hacky way, there's no need to manipulate the classfiles directly (it is far more complicated): the easy way is to download the project, read the docs how to set it up (so you can compile it with cmd w/o errors), add your patch, compile it, *then* you can update the used JAR file with the new class file (or files: note that there might be multiple files generated if you're using inner classes or lambdas). Just don't forget to mention that somewhere in the docs, because otherwise no one will ever know that the library is slightly modified...

Comment: After further research I found that the JCIFS library consist of a zip file that contains a bunch of java files and so I am thinking of adding a java class into it and re-compile it making a whole new jar file again with the use of apache ant. However, it seems like while doing so, I encountered another error saying "Build Failed" whenever I entered the command "ant jar". So May I know if you have any idea/hints on how I could solve this? thank you

Comment: A Jar is a zip file with a META-INF folder. The project is open source and they ship the src with the jar (sometimes happens, sometimes there is a different jar file for the src, etc.). Check the project site for docs how to compile.