# How do i edit file with .class extension?

Tags: java, plugins, edit

i've to modify a plugin for my minecraft server (yes, i'm allowed to do it).
The problem is that the files that i've to modify have .class extension and despite a found a way to see those files with jd-Gui, i did not found a way to edit them. Can you please explain me step by step how to do it?

p.s. I use MacOsX system.

Thanks to all of you.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228911/how-to-create-edit-class-file-codes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a good idea to edit .class files because of dependencies and relationship with other classes. Also because .class contains byte information and not recommended (not possible in many cases) to edit it manually. The file is generated when you compile your java file. So, find the java source file, compile it, and it will update the .class file.
Good luck.

Comment: ok, i found source code, i've to open it whit eclipse?

Comment: Yes you can use eclipse or bluej or any other IDE you use and you will see complete program with all relationships and classes. Don't copy that source file. because you may leave other relevant classes behind. Instead open the source file from its original location.

Comment: ok, i don't know how but i downloaded it whit maven, i modified i little part of .java file. Now how can i compile it in .jar so that i can test it?